# vagrant openshift origin how-to connect to console?

Tags: vagrant, openshift-origin

I am a openshift origin noob and I try to install it on my laptop & play with it...
On windows 7 I have installed vagrant, virtualbox and Vagrant-openshift plugin (https://github.com/openshift/vagrant-openshift)

I have created the box & is starting when I do vagrant up & I can connect using ssh to the machine

My question is what do I need to do next?
How can I connect to the web console of openshift?
Where do i need to install rhc and how? to be able to create/deploy apps?

Thank you,
Bogdan

Comment: Hi @bogdanbrudiu, can you resolve this issue? I have the same issue, vagrant seems to run correctly but i cannot connect to console. I am trying it on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Once installed, you can access Openshift console at https://hostname-OR-IP:8443/console

If you can't access check the status of your routes with ip route and verify that the vagrant default interface(usually eth0) is not configured as the default route.

If you are able to login in the server, you can run oc and oadm commands to create/configure apps.

Comment: Hi @Ferrandinand. Can you give an example of how to manage routes on vagrant? I have the same issue, vagrant seems to run correctly but i cannot connect to console. When i run `vagrant service-manager env` command i see openshift is serving from https://10.0.2.15:8443/console

Answer (score -1):

i think that windows isn't a good plataform to install openshift, if you have a VM try to install CentOS 6 or fedora (or RHEL 6 if you have access to any distribution) there's a very larger amount of information to these OS than windows, or you just can install the openshift OS distribution that is supposed to do everything for you, you only have to configure the DNS server and DHCP and a few thing that scripts doesn't can do for you.

If you try to install it on one of the Linux distribution mentioned above you can just install it from the webpage or try to install from the deployment guide that is very complete: www.openshift.org/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html

In my personal experience i had a very hard time with the deployment guide but it worth if you think in the knowledge and experience that you gain.

all is there, hope it weren't too late to answer you.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer to the question.